# How do I allow full inbound and outbound internet access to Docker Containers on a custom network?

Tags: docker, dns, synology

This has been driving me up the wall for the last week, as my Docker environment now no longer works (after server hell and backup configs not resolving the issue).

1. I have created a custom network ("custom") in Docker, which has an internal IP range of 172.18.0.0/16.
2. All my Docker containers are attached to "custom".
3. I have a host DNS server which is functioning correctly for both local domains and remote (using forward first).
4. I have reverse proxies configured which, depending on the IPtables being correct, work.
5. All IPtables configuration has been automatically generated. I don't know enough to tell if they are correct or not.

I want to be able to:

- Connect to any of my Docker containers via a URL (e.g. sub.domain.com).
- For some containers to be able to connect to a MySQL DB on the local host via IP and port.
- For some containers to be able to resolve DNS and access the internet.
- With the current setup I have, I cannot access my Containers via URL,
  but I can if I go directly the host IP and exposed Docker port (i.e.
  https://sub.domain.com does not work, but http://192.168.1.2:9000
  does).
- The containers do not connect to the MySQL DB where the
  configuration points to the "custom" gateway (i.e. 172.18.0.1:3306).
- The containers cannot resolve DNS. The DNS is set (correctly) in the
  container /etc/resolv.conf to 127.0.0.11, which should then forward
  all requests on to the host DNS (192.168.1.2:53). If I force the DNS to the bridge gateway on the Container, then I can see requests hitting the host DNS but not being returned.
- If the container is on the default bridge, the DNS is set to the host DNS (192.168.1.2), but won't resolve any requests. If I force the DNS to the bridge gateway on the Container, then I can resolve DNS requests.

I would be extremely grateful if someone could help, as I had this working previously and I cannot see what I can possibly have set up incorrectly!

The IPTables are below:

```
#FILTER TABLE

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination                

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.2           tcp dpt:36330
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.2           tcp dpt:7396
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:9000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.3           tcp dpt:7999
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.3           tcp dpt:7990

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

#NAT TABLE

Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DEFAULT_OUTPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DEFAULT_POSTROUTING  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DEFAULT_OUTPUT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere            !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain DEFAULT_POSTROUTING (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.18.0.0/16        anywhere            
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16        anywhere            
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.18.0.2           172.18.0.2           tcp dpt:36330
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.18.0.2           172.18.0.2           tcp dpt:7396
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.17.0.2           172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:9000
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.18.0.3           172.18.0.3           tcp dpt:7999
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.18.0.3           172.18.0.3           tcp dpt:7990

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:36330 to:172.18.0.2:36330
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:7396 to:172.18.0.2:7396
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:9000 to:172.17.0.2:9000
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:7999 to:172.18.0.3:7999
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:7990 to:172.18.0.3:7990
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I blew the entire server away and started from scratch, along with some backups. I think the entire configuration was up the spout.